# Data/Information Availability

Tags: plasma

In the Plasma whitepaper, they refer several times to "data availability".
What does this mean exactly?

> This needs to be able to minimize issues around the data availability problem (i.e. block withholding) [...]
>
> this proposal is primarily around data availability and encouraging cost minimiza- tion around fraud proofs[...]

Answer (score 4):

Data availability problem is basically, that if someone withholds some data in a block, we cannot verify 100% the state, even if the block is valid as a whole. So its like a valid block but with some data not available to the network. [Read more here](https://github.com/ethereum/research/wiki/A-note-on-data-availability-and-erasure-coding) or [watch here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJT_fR7wexw)